# using NISIS uninstaller to create an uninstaller

Tags: nsis

I am getting an error when I am trying to uninstall an application. I used NSIS to make installer and uninstaller for it. The application is uninstalled but it is not getting removed from the add/remove programs. the error looks like "an error occurred while trying to uninstall it may have already been uninstalled"

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the registry key relation to the Add/Remove Programs registration in your uninstall section.

See also the last paragraph of section "Required values" [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Add_uninstall_information_to_Add/Remove_Programs).

For example, it could look like this:

```
Section Uninstall
    ; ...here the existing uninstall code goes...

    DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WhateverNameYouHadUsedHereBefore"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: I already did that... i have added two lines. they are   DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"

Comment: Are you sure it is executed? Maybe something in your logic makes you jump over this line. You could try adding a message box after the line and see whether it opens when you uninstall.

Comment: PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY tells us nothing when you don't show the actual value. Why did you not include these in your question?